# RavenDB. How to load document with only 5 items from inner collection?

Tags: .net, nosql, ravendb, document-database

Here is a document in the store:

```
{
    "Name": "Hibernating Rhinos", 
    "Employees": [
        { "Name": "Ayende" },
        { "Name": "John" },
        { "Name": "Bob" },
        { "Name": "Tom" },
        { "Name": "Lane" },
        { "Name": "Bill" },
        { "Name": "Tad" }
     ]
}
```

It is easy to load this document with or without **Employees** collection, but how to load only part of inner collection? For instance, first 5 items:

```
{
    "Name": "Hibernating Rhinos", 
    "Employees": [
        { "Name": "Ayende" },
        { "Name": "John" },
        { "Name": "Bob" },
        { "Name": "Tom" },
        { "Name": "Lane" }
     ]
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not directly, not.

What you can do is define the following index:

```
from company in docs.Companies
from emp in company.Employees
select new { Compnany = company.Name, Employee = emp }
```

You can then query the index for the first five employees

Answer (score 0):

You can use Live Projections feature of RavenDB. Put this query in TransformResults function of your index:
I assume that your document name is Company.

```
TransformResults = (database, companies) => from c in companies
                                        select new {Company=c,Employees=c.Employees.Take(5)};
```